# Receiving 404 for RestControllers in spring

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am new to Spring MVC and trying to build a basic hello world example Using AngularJS and SpringMVC (Uisng Maven and Eclipse). 
After going through some tutorials on internet I have done following things

Web MVC Configurations

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/")
            .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(new WebJarsResourceResolver())
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

Servlet Initializer

```
    public class SampleInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig .class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        Filter [] singleton = { new CORSFilter() };
        return singleton;
    }

}
```

CORS Filter

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

SampleController :

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {


    @RequestMapping(path = "/sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<String> listUsers() {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add("user1");
        return result;
    }

}
```

Webapp structure

[image]
app.js [Routing using route provider - code Snippet]

```
angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies' ,'ngTable'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
```

Tomcat Settings :

Since there is no WEB-INF/web.xml , I have removed it from 
tomcat-8\conf\context.xml

```
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the-->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.-->
    <!--<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>-->
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
```

In tomcat-8\conf\web.xml I see that index.html has been mentioned as Welcome file

When I deploy my application to tomcat , its able to display index.html and due to my routing code , its able to route to login.html . But when I am trying to access the rest service , it shows 404 HTTP Status .

Is there some other setting which I need to maintain somewhere ?
I have re-checked my RestService code and it seems to be correct to me. Also I have checked the tomcat log and it doesn't shows any error either.

Also If possible , can you please point me to a good step by step tutorial of using AngularJS with Spring based Rest Services (Using maven )

Comment: what is the url that you are using to access REST service?

Comment: I am making a rest call to http://localhost:8081/HelloWorldApp/sample . I have also tried http://localhost:8081/HelloWorldApp/sample/ [I have changed the default tomcat port to 8081]

Comment: You are missing entry of DispatcherServlet in web.xml. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21128558/1421189 . Or If possible use spring boot in which you won't need to do this configurations manually. Refer https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: My project doesn't have web.xml . Are you talking about Tomcat's web.xml ?